# Install matlab engine for Python when trial version of MATLAB is installed in Windows

Tags: python, matlab

How to install matlab engine for Python when trial version of MATLAB is installed in Windows? I tried with the following in command window:

```
cd C:\....\extern\engine\python
python setup.py install
```

But command window shows an error:

```
running install
running build
running build.py
creating build
error: Could not create 'build': Access is denied.
```

Is it happening because of the trial version? I use a trial version of MATLAB 2015b which connects to internet and asks for password during start of MATLAB in MATLAB GUI. I am using Python (x,y) 2.7. How to install matlab engine with this trial version of MATLAB 2015b?

Comment: It seems to be an issue of insuficcient write permissions, take a look at the build.py to understand where the directory should be created and modify the permissions or try starting the python.exe with administrative permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've met the same problem just like you, and my solution is right clicking the icon of powershell then choose Run ISE with admin, then do what you do before, and you can install matlab engine successfully.